# How to weight smoothing by arbitrary factor in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following is a relevant example. I'm looking at shot efficiency as a function of distance for NBA players. I want to weight the smoothing by the volume of shots taken at each distance (i.e. the size of the bubbles). Is there a way to do this? The command to generate this plot was:

```
ggplot(top10,aes(x=FT,y=PPS,size=FGA,color=PPS))
+scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 30))
+scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2.2))+geom_point()
+facet_grid(NAME~.,space="free")
+stat_smooth(color="darkblue",size=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can just add `weight=FGA` to your list of mappings in the first line ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! You know what's funny is that I tried putting "weight=FGA" in the stat_smooth function, but it didn't work. But it does work putting it at the top.

Comment: To include it within `stat_smooth` you probably needed to specify it as`mapping=aes(weight=FGA)` (rather than just `weight=FGA`) -- i.e. make it an aesthetic mapping rather than a hard-coded value ... ?

Answer (score 19):

As Ben noted above, if you change the first line to

```
ggplot(top10,aes(x=FT,y=PPS,size=FGA,color=PPS,weight=FGA))
```

it works.

Here's a corrected version:

[image]

Comment: But beware a little of the standard errors. There are many types of weights.

Comment: Do u know where this weight mapping/argument is documented? I've looked everywhere, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have multiple smooth lines you could do the weighting in each graph separately:

```
ggplot(top10,aes(x=FT,y=PPS,size=FGA,color=PPS))
+scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 30))
+scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2.2))+geom_point()
+facet_grid(NAME~.,space="free")
+stat_smooth(color="darkblue",size=2, aes(weight= FGA))
```